# EditItemTemplate values not getting read properly

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I am trying to build a simple `GridView`.
I have a `Products` table and it contains `ProductID` and `ModelName`.
I am using `LINQ` to `SQL`

My `GridView` code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="objData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataKeyNames="ProductID,ModelName">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ModelName") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ModelName") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

and my `datasource` code is

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objData" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAll" UpdateMethod="UpdateProduct" 
        DataObjectTypeName="TestLINQProto.tblProduct" TypeName="TestLINQProto.ProductsList"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I have my `update` method written like this

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update,true)]
        public void UpdateProduct(tblProduct product)
        {
            EshopDataAccess.UpdateProduct(product);//This will call a LINQ function to update the product
        }
```

The issue is that the `tblProduct` that the `UpdateProduct` contain original values. It is not getting the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using `Eval` method which only supports reading/fetching of data. Use `Bind` Method in your grid aspx code. Like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="objData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataKeyNames="ProductID,ModelName">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ModelName") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ModelName") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```